# Is it normal to experience large overhead using the 1:1 threading that comes in the standard library?

Tags: rust

While working through learning Rust, a friend asked me to see what kind of performance I could get out of Rust for generating the first 1 million prime numbers both single-threaded and multi-threaded. After trying several implementations, I'm just stumped. Here is the kind of performance that I'm seeing:

```
rust_primes --threads 8 --verbose --count 1000000
Options { verbose: true, count: 1000000, threads: 8 }
Non-concurrent using while (15485863): 2.814 seconds.
Concurrent using mutexes (15485863): 876.561 seconds.
Concurrent using channels (15485863): 798.217 seconds.
```

Without overloading the question with too much code, here are the methods responsible for each of the benchmarks:

```
fn non_concurrent(options: &Options) {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut current = 0;

    let ts = Instant::now();
    while count < options.count {
        if is_prime(current) {
            count += 1;
        }
        current += 1;
    }
    let d = ts.elapsed();
    println!("Non-concurrent using while ({}): {}.{} seconds.", current - 1, d.as_secs(), d.subsec_nanos() / 1_000_000);
}

fn concurrent_mutex(options: &Options) {
    let count = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let highest = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let mut cc = 0;
    let mut current = 0;

    let ts = Instant::now();

    while cc < options.count {
        let mut handles = vec![];
        for x in current..(current + options.threads) {
            let count = Arc::clone(&count);
            let highest = Arc::clone(&highest);
            let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                if is_prime(x) {
                    let mut c = count.lock().unwrap();
                    let mut h = highest.lock().unwrap();
                    *c += 1;
                    if x > *h {
                        *h = x;
                    }
                }
            });
            handles.push(handle);
        }

        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }

        cc = *count.lock().unwrap();
        current += options.threads;
    }

    let d = ts.elapsed();
    println!("Concurrent using mutexes ({}): {}.{} seconds.", *highest.lock().unwrap(), d.as_secs(), d.subsec_nanos() / 1_000_000);
}

fn concurrent_channel(options: &Options) {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut current = 0;
    let mut highest = 0;

    let ts = Instant::now();

    while count < options.count {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

        for x in current..(current + options.threads) {
            let txc = mpsc::Sender::clone(&tx);

            thread::spawn(move || {
                if is_prime(x) {
                    txc.send(x).unwrap();
                }
            });
        }

        drop(tx);

        for message in rx {
            count += 1;

            if message > highest && count <= options.count {
                highest = message;
            }
        }

        current += options.threads;
    }

    let d = ts.elapsed();
    println!("Concurrent using channels ({}): {}.{} seconds.", highest, d.as_secs(), d.subsec_nanos() / 1_000_000);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this normal performance with the 1:1 threading that comes in the standard library?

Here is a MCVE that shows the same problem. I didn't limit the number of threads it starts up at once here like I did in the code above. The point is, threading seems to have a very significant overhead unless I'm doing something horribly wrong.

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Instant;
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let iterations = 100_000;
    non_threaded(iterations);
    threaded(iterations);
}

fn threaded(iterations: u32) {
    let tx = Instant::now();
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let mut handles = vec![];

    for _ in 0..iterations {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
            *num = test(*num);
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    let d = tx.elapsed();

    println!("Threaded in {}.", dur_to_string(d));
}

fn non_threaded(iterations: u32) {
    let tx = Instant::now();
    let mut _q = 0;
    for x in 0..iterations {
        _q = test(x + 1);
    }

    let d = tx.elapsed();
    println!("Non-threaded in {}.", dur_to_string(d));
}

fn dur_to_string(d: Duration) -> String {
    let mut s = d.as_secs().to_string();
    s.push_str(".");
    s.push_str(&(d.subsec_nanos() / 1_000_000).to_string());
    s
}

fn test(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}
```

Here are the results of this on my machine:

```
Non-threaded in 0.9.
Threaded in 5.785.
```

Comment: Are you already familiar with what happens when you spawn a thread? Have you calculated how many threads you are starting in total? What prevents you from trying with a thread pool?

Comment: The number of threads that I spawn with each iteration of the while loop is controlled by an argument passed into the program and stored in options.threads (in the case of the example, 8). Each iteration of the while loop waits until those (8) threads finish before spawning 8 more. TRPL did not cover thread pools, so I'm familiar with it.

Comment: Not per iteration; *in total*. Please go ahead and [edit] your question to contain a [MCVE]. Ideally, we should be able to copy-paste your code and run it ourselves to reproduce the same behavior. You should make it **minimal** — we don't need to see the command line parsing, for example. Your implementation of `is_prime` can even always return `true` if it continues to have the same behavior.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the rust standard library. If you used equivalent primitives in any other language you would incur similar overhead. You are spawning new threads, performing allocations etc. for each integer computation. If anything it is surprising that the overhead is merely a factor of 400.

Comment: @the8472 I think OPs point is more that the "primitives" exposed by the standard library are full-on threads. In other languages (Go, Erlang, etc), the primitives are more lightweight. OP mentions "1:1 threading" as opposed to "M:N threading". So, yes, if you used equivalent primitives (a.k.a. system threads) you'd expect similar behavior, but the primitives provided by Rust's standard library appear heavier than the primitives of other languages.

Comment: Sure, but those are quite different primitives that needs to be used differently. If you use threads to compute primes you might use shared memory and CAS or batching if you build it from low-level blocks instead of relying on the stack juggling of green threads, which comes with its own costs. If that's really what OP meant it's basically an apples and oranges question. Yes, they're separate fruits and yes they taste differently, this is expected behavior. Ideally this would have been asked in a more general manner, comparing primitives, not rust vs X.

Comment: Even with goroutines or Erlang processes, this code spawns 8 of them each iteration, of which (after the first iteration) at most 3 ever find a prime. Furthermore (assuming `is_prime` uses trial division with early return), when one does find a prime, we wait for it to finish trying to factorize it before spawning more, so as the numbers grow, we spend most of our time waiting on just a single thread. Since twin primes are sparse, the asymptotic performance of either "concurrent" solution is therefore just as bad as the "non-concurrent" solution, even if concurrency primitives are free!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> threading seems to have a very significant overhead

It's not the general concept of "threading", it's the concept of creating and destroying lots of threads.

By default in Rust 1.22.1, [each spawned thread allocates 2MiB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/#stack-size) of memory to use as stack space. In the worst case, your MCVE could allocate ~200GiB of RAM. In reality, this is unlikely to happen as some threads will exit, memory will be reused, etc. I only saw it use ~400MiB.

On top of that, there is overhead involved with inter-thread communication (`Mutex`, channels, `Atomic*`) compared to intra-thread variables. Some kind of locking needs to be performed to ensure that all threads see the same data. "Embarrassingly parallel" algorithms tend to not have a lot of communication required. There are also different amounts of time required for different communication primitives. Atomic variables tend to be faster than others in many cases, but aren't as widely usable.

Then there's compiler optimizations to account for. Non-threaded code is way easier to optimize compared to threaded code. For example, running your code in release mode shows:

```
Non-threaded in 0.0.
Threaded in 142.775.
```

That's right, the non-threaded code took **no time**. The compiler can see through the code and realizes that nothing actually happens and removes it all. I don't know how you got 5 seconds for the threaded code as opposed to the 2+ minutes I saw.

---

Switching to a threadpool will reduce a lot of the unneeded creation of threads. We can also use a threadpool that provides *scoped threads*, which allows us to avoid the `Arc` as well:

```
extern crate scoped_threadpool;

use scoped_threadpool::Pool;

fn threaded(iterations: u32) {
    let tx = Instant::now();
    let counter = Mutex::new(0);

    let mut pool = Pool::new(8);

    pool.scoped(|scope| {
        for _ in 0..iterations {
            scope.execute(|| {
                let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
                *num = test(*num);
            });
        }
    });
    let d = tx.elapsed();

    println!("Threaded in {}.", dur_to_string(d));
}
```

```
Non-threaded in 0.0.
Threaded in 0.675.
```

As with most pieces of programming, it's crucial to understand the tools you have and to use them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. I did do another test earlier using the threadpool crate but it still had some poor performance. I'll give the scoped_threadpool a try, but I'll also accept your thorough reply as the answer.

Comment: Note that while a new thread "allocates" 2MB of stack space, this does not mean that the OS actually maps 2MB of physical memory to the stack.  It will generally map significantly less than that, and only increase the amount of physical memory if the memory is actually accessed.